# Send an Integer back to the previous View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, alert

Hello I am trying to pass back a variable that has the level number.  After the user clears the round below is called

```
        if enemyHP <= 0.0{
            level = level + 1                
            battle(winPlayer:true)
        }
```

then function battle is called

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "finished！", message: finishedMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Go Back",style:.default,handler:{action in


        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
        self.present(alert,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

I am trying to display the level number in the previous view controller so I need the variable level to go be passed back. What is the best way for this? I have used segues and it doesn't work with the alert.

Delegate

```
protocol DataSentDelegate {

    func Back(data: Int)
}
```

I used

```
delegate?.Back(data: level)
```

In the previous ViewController I added

```
func Back(data: Int){
   new = data
}


print(new)
```

It doesn't appear.

Comment: Your code will not work. You are dismissing then you are presenting???

Comment: @Brandon Hello it does work. It shows the alert and it brings me back. I am having trouble passing the variable back

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: @Satsuki Enjoy your race condition. Your code doesn’t work. You are calling dismiss on self (asynchronously). Then you are calling present alert on self (also async). Tell me how that will work. Problem: dismissing self then presenting an alert on it will give you “cannot present alert on detached viewcontroller” warning..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the *dismiss-present* methods, you should use a segue and then pass the object in *prepare(for:sender:)* this way:

```
func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?) 
{
    if segue.identifier == "Back" // Give it any name
    {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? MyViewController // NOTE: this is your custom view controller class
        {
            destination.level = yourDesiredValue
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** to perform the segue:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "finished！", message: finishedMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Go Back",style:.default,handler:{action in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Back", sender: nil)
}
self.present(alert,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for your answer, I know about the segues but will this work with the alert?

Comment: @Satsuki I'm not sure what you are trying to do, and I don't understand why you try to present the alert inside the same alert's completion callback. I suppose that you want to present the alert outside the completion block, and you want to perform the segue when the user presses the "Go Back" action of the alert. I edited the answer, I hope it helps.